# Formula or script for highest number starts with alpha

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, worksheet-function

I am looking for a formula or script that can show me the highest number within a range of values that have a leading alpha character. For example:

```
D101
D102
D103
D104
J101
J102
J103
```

I would like a cell that shows the highest D# in column is: `D104` & highest J# in col is `J103`.

I tried using `RIGHT`, in combination with `MAX` but was unsuccessful. This is the formula I tried which evaluates to `0`:

```
=MAXA(B:B,RIGHT(B:B,3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=ArrayFormula(max(value(right(filter(A:A,Left(A:A)="D"),3))))
```

and adjust `D` to the letter of your choice (or parameterise it).

[MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013)
[VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220)
[RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087)
[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
[LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079)

Expect `0` from attempts at maths operations on string functions since these always return Text.

Comment: this worked great- thanks alot for your expertise!